# How to get data from website into Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas, parsing, screen-scraping

I need to write a Python script that will use data from a website [like this link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in) and put it into a `pandas` dataframe.

My try is

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in"

r =  requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

league_table = soup.find('table', class_ = "table.ws-table-all.notranslate")

print(league_table)
```

And I got output: `None`

Comment: maybe its the wrong link, if I open the one you posted and look at the HTML, I do not see any table having the `class` attribute you specified

Comment: The thing is   get table it should be sql statement "SELECT * FROM [Customers]", than by checking html code it appears. 
Maybe it is possible to get data from Web sql, but i cannot find a solution how to do it

Comment: Use browser automation so as to enter the SQL and click the button then retrieve the returned table if valid SQL. The database and the SQL qry are run dynamically through JS executing as detailed in the js source files